# Where to put file that a jar needs to load

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have a `jar` that will be connecting to a website for communication using `websockets`. The website is an **SSL** site and for that reason I have a `.ts` the program needs to load file. The following is the java code used to load that .ts file

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",
            "foo.ts");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
```

and the java program is in a package called `foo.web` so thus when packed into the jar is in a folder called `foo` which then has a subfolder called `web`.

My question is, do I put the `foo.ts` in the `foo/web` folder where my classes reside or should I put the `foo.ts` file at the root of the jar to be loaded with my current code in the program for loading the `foo.ts` file?

Comment: Both locations will be searched starting with "classes" before "libs", I prefer putting it in "classes" personally...

Comment: huh to the classes before libs?

Comment: @Bret sorry forget to tag you in the comment before.

Comment: If you put the files in both places, it should load the one in "classes" and ignore the one in the lib

Comment: @Bret gotcha now thanks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The work around System.setProperty... needing a 'regular' file path, is using mechanism to resolve class resources:

- place ts file in your code folder under some package (normal web code not
  a library jar code)
- in a class from the same package, call:

a

```
//this will find the file in the package folder
URL cert = this.getClass().getResource("ts");
String path = cert.toString(); //this translate the url to file system location
if (path.startsWith("file:"))
path = path.substring("file:".length()+1,path.length()); //getting rid of file prefix as not needed
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", path);
```

If you want to include ts in jar, similar trick, but instead of path (which will not work, read the content and save it to temporary location

```
in  = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(wsdl);
... save it to tmp location
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", your tmp location);
```

Comment: that did help and yea the only pain I have is how the whole thing I am working on is being built. But figured out a solution to keep with the build how it should be. Put it in the tomcat/ssl folder I made for tomcat that holds the tomcat keys sicne tomcat and the application talking to the website will always be on same computer.

Comment: If you have control over tomcat you can import the ts to the tomcat: 
when starting tomcat add: 
set JAVA_OPTS= -Djava.net.ssl.trustStore=YOUR_TS -Djavax.net.trustStorePassword=PASS (if not the default is changeit)

You can import your certificat to orginal java CA and then use it, so your tomcat will be able to resolve the 'regular' authorities

Comment: I thought I had to also load it into the external application that will be connecting to the websocket server tomcat is running on an ssl (443) port? If I don't have to please excuse me and tell me the correct way to do it as I just know the tomcat basics nothing too in depth.

Comment: I will try to explain in an answer below as commenting is anoying

Comment: if there are web resources you can happily point me to those as well.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have unsigned, self generated certificate that you want to use for your ssl connection.

The part that servers the content over ssl, (your tomcat on 443 or apache) needs to know the certificate and its key (configured as in tomcat or apache document).
Your java code that is deployed on that server, does not need to knwo about the certificate or even that is behind ssl.

But the code that wants to connect to such server, lets say web service client will throw exception (and very obscured btw) as it will not recognize the certificate and refuse connecting (unlike the web browser which ofer the dialog that lets you add an exception).
So the client code needs the certificate added to its TrustedStore before oppening connection (the trick with System.property does the job). Thanks to it the client can trust the connection as your remote cert matches the one he already has.

If your client code happens to be running on the same tomcat, it still needs the cert added to the store, as the configuration options for connector at 443 only expose the cert to anyone who can read it, but do not add it to the tomcat's pool of know certificates. To do so you need the -Djava.net.ssl.trustStore=YOUR_TS -Djavax.net.trustStorePassword=PASS options for tomcat starts, or the System.setProperty inside your application code.

Comment: If you have signed, proper certificate you don't need to add it to the store, all will work fine if only you configure the ssl connector on tomcat correctly (the tomcat docs is detailed enought).

Answer (score 0):

The value of the javax.net.ssl.trustStore property is a file path that points to the location of the trust store on disk. If you don't specify a folder, it will assume the current working directory for the program which is most likely where the JVM was invoked from. If you are unsure what your current working directory is, you can get it from the user.dir system property.

```
System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Comment: I am however talking about the jar, i am asking will it know its in the jar or will it be like nope can't find this.

Comment: The javax..net.ssl.trustStore system property must point to a valid file path. It will not look inside your jar.